# mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have recently updated to php version 5.5 and began updating the code to mysqli. I have resolved most issues but I am stuck on this one. I get the error "mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in"

All Help and pointers would be appreciated

```
<?php
/*
 * ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
 * Copyright 2007 Adobe Systems Incorporated
 * All Rights Reserved
 * 
 * NOTICE:  Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file in accordance with the 
 * terms of the Adobe license agreement accompanying it. If you have received this file from a 
 * source other than Adobe, then your use, modification, or distribution of it requires the prior 
 * written permission of Adobe.
 */

/*
    Copyright (c) InterAKT Online 2000-2006. All rights reserved.
*/

/**
 * The connection class (used on PHP - MySQL Server model)
 */
class KT_Connection {

    /**
     * The database name
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    var $databaseName = '';

    /**
     * The connection Resource ID
     * @var object ResourceID
     * @access private
     */
    var $connection = null;

    /**
     * Flag. what server model is.
     * @var string
     * @access private
     */
    var $servermodel = "mysql";

    /**
     * for ADODB compatibility
     * @var string
     * @access public
     */
    var $databaseType = "mysql";

    /**
     * The constructor
     * Sets the connection and the database name
     * @param object ResourceID &$connection
     * @param string $databasename
     * @access public
     */
    function KT_Connection(&$connection, $databasename) {
        $this->connection = &$connection;
        $this->databaseName = $databasename;
    }

    /**
     * Executes a SQL statement
     * @param string $sql
     * @return object unknown
     *         true on success
     *         response Resource ID if one is returned by the wrapper function
     * @access public
     */
    function Execute($sql) {
        if (!mysqli_select_db($this->connection , $this->databaseName)) {
            return false;
        }           
        $response = mysqli_query($this->connection , $sql);
        if (!is_resource($response)) {
            return $response;
        } else {
            $recordset = new KT_Recordset($response);
            return $recordset;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes a SQL statement
     * @param string $sql
     * @return mysql resource
     *         true on success
     *         response MYSQL Resource ID
     * @access public
     */
    function MySQL_Execute($sql) {
        if (!mysqli_select_db($this->connection , $this->databaseName)) {
            return false;
        }   
        $response = mysqli_query($this->connection , $sql);
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the error message
     * @return string
     * @access public
     */
    function ErrorMsg() {
        return mysqli_error($this->connection);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the auto-generated inserted id (if any)
     * @return object unknown
     * @access public
     */
    function Insert_ID($table, $pKeyCol) {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The code you posted is correct. (Well apart from PHP 5.5 being after its end-of-life and the constructor called `KT_Connection()` instead of `__construct()`.)

Comment: But generally the error means that you are not passing database connection handle as the first parameter to `mysqli_select_db()` but rather a string, which is not correct.